# Diff of two csv. Memory usage to high

Tags: php, arrays

you helped me so much time but now to this Problem i didn´t find a solution yet.
I have two csv which i had to compare and get the differences.
Both csv looks like this:

```
https://stackoverflow.com
https://google.com
```

Both files are about 10 MB

Till now i make this:

```
array1 = array_map('str_getcsv', file(file1));
array2 = array_map('str_getcsv', file(file2));
$diff = array_diff(array_map('serialize',$array1), array_map('serialize',$array2 ));
```

it works very nice so long as i have unlimited memory.
And thats the problem;-) i don´t have unlimited memory because the server is not the same as befor.

So now the question is:

How can i reduce the memory_usage of it or how can i compare two files. 
Please don´t think of filesize or so what.

I need the real differences of the file.

Like in one file it stands

```
 https://stackoverflow.com
```

and in the other

```
https://google.com
```

so the difference is both:-)

thanks for your help guys

Comment: How are `stackoverflow.com` and `google.com` CSV files?

Comment: Instead of serializing them, why not just compare `file(file1)` with `file(file2)`?

Comment: Sorry fo my delay.
in the CSV1 ist stnad https://stackoverflow.com and in CSV2 stands google.com.

so the difference are both;-)

Comment: You mean those are just example lines in the files?

Answer (score 0):

Read `file1` into the keys of an associative array. Then read `file2` line by line, removing those entries from the array.

```
$file1 = array_flip(file("file1.csv", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES));
$fd2 = fopen("file2.csv");
$diff = array();
while ($line = fgets($fd2)) {
    $line = str_replace("\n", "", $line); // remove trailing newline
    if (!array_key_exists($line, $file1)) {
        // line is only in file2, add it to result
        $diff[] = $line;
    } else {
        // line is in both files, remove it from $file1
        unset($file1[$line]);
    }
}
fclose($fd2);
// Remaining keys in $file1 are unique to that file
$diff += array_keys($file1);
```

If reading the first file into an array and then flipping it is too much memory, you could do that with an `fgets()` loop as well (but the garbage collector should clean up the temporary array created by `file()`).

Comment: Nice answer:-) but it doen´t change the memory usage:-( sorry:-(
Do you have another idea for me?

Comment: I find that hard to believe. This should use about half as much memory as your program, since it only creates one array instead of two. Did you try what I suggested about creating the array line by line instead of using `array_flip()`?

Comment: Yes it halfed the memomy but it was too much.

Comment: Nwo i found the issue....it was not in this function. it was in a function before that fill the csv. Thanks for your helf. I leraned something more through your answer. Thanks!!!